# How i can put a recaptcha with devise controller in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tengo este codigo:

En app/views/devise/registrations yo tengo el siguente codigo:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">

        <h2 class="text-center">Sign up</h2>
        <br/>

        <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
          <%= render 'shared/devisemes' %>

          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.text_field :fullname, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Full name", class: "form-control" %>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Email", class: "form-control" %>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", placeholder: "Password", class: "form-control"  %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
             <%= recaptcha_tags %>
          </div>
          <div class="actions">
            <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: "btn btn-primary"  %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

En app/controllore/application_controller.rb tengo este codigo:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:fullname])
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:fullname])
  end
end
```

En secret.yml Tengo lo siguiente:

```
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
  #recaptcha_site_key: <%= ENV["RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY"] %>
  #recaptcha_secret_key: <%= ENV["RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY"] %>
```

He puesto la gema correcta en el archivo de gemafile, y he leido varios ejemplos pero no se como implementar recaptcha cuando el devise parameter.
Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: Hola Diego, este sitio es **en español**, por tanto las preguntas son realizadas en tal idioma. Favor de editar tu pregunta para que cumpla la norma, gracias

Comment: Respecto a tu pregunta, ¿que has buscado o hecho para implementar el recaptcha? ¿has seguido la [wiki de devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-Recaptcha-with-Devise) donde indica como hacerlo? ¿te muestra algún error? ¿que muestra/no muestra tu aplicación?

Comment: Es que yo solo tengo application_controller.rb y pages_controller.rb dentro de aplicacion en la carpeta controllers tal como indico y creo y edito usuarios atraves del devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit

Answer (score 0):

Para implementar el recaptcha puedes instalar la gema recaptcha con

```
gem "recaptcha", require: "recaptcha/rails"
```

Para más información sobre esta gema visita este [link](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha).

En está [página](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-Recaptcha-with-Devise) puedes ver mas informacion de como integrarlo con devise.

### Basicamente dice que:

- instales la gema recaptcha
- Añadas `<%= recaptcha_tags %>` a la forma donde quieras agregar recaptcha con esto ya te saldrá el recaptcha.
- Incluir `prepend_before_action` en la accion del controller donde implementes el recaptcha.

Si lo que quieres es agregrarlo en el registro el siguiente codigo te servira.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  prepend_before_action :check_captcha, only: [:create] # Change this to be any actions you want to protect.

  private
    def check_captcha
      unless verify_recaptcha
        self.resource = resource_class.new sign_up_params
        resource.validate # Look for any other validation errors besides Recaptcha
        respond_with_navigational(resource) { render :new }
      end 
    end
end
```